# HTML email image map not working on Android

Tags: html, email, html-email, imagemap

I want to have an HTML imagemap in the body of an email, like so:

```
<img src='bg.jpg' name='background' id='background' alt='background' usemap='#Map' />
<map name='Map' id='Map'>
<area alt='' title='' href='http://dell.com' shape='poly' coords='1,128,48,128,48,60,0,60' />
<area alt='' title='' href='http://google.com' shape='poly' coords='0,0,48,0,48,60,0,60' />
</map>
```

It works on desktop (Outlook & gmail), it works on iOS (Mail & Gmail). I can't make it work on Android for the life of me.

Does anyone have any experience with this at all?

Comment: Is the image being resized on mobile?

Comment: It is not. I thought that might be the problem so I wrapped the imagemap in a table to stop it being resized.

Comment: What android is this on Gmail app, Samsung or android 4.4 and below?

Comment: Tested on a couple of different Samsung galaxy devices

Comment: If its shrinking the image then the image map will not work.